# SWT FileDialog Browse Location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a simple file dialog in my RCP application which lets the users to select a file as per the code snippet below

```java
Label filePathLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NULL);
filePathLabel.setText("File Path");
Text filePathText = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
filePathText.setText("");
Button browseButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(getShell(), SWT.SAVE);
fileDialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] {"*.txt"});
fileDialog.setFilterNames(new String[] {"Textfiles(*.txt)"});

browseButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
 {
  @override
   public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
   {
    String path = fileDialog.open();
    if(path != null && !path.isEmpty()) 
    {
     filePathText.setText(path);
    }
   }
 });
```

The problem I'm facing is that I have not been able to get the previous browse location of the file after I close my RCP application and start it again since all the controls (Text, FileDialog) will be recreated. I save the result of `fileDialog.open` which returns the path and set the `filePathText` Text control's `setText(Text text)` method whenever my `WizardPage` is reopened to show the previous browse location selected but I loose access to the browse location after I close my RCP application so the next time I reopen my application I have not been able to set the `filePathText` text to the previously browsed location **even though Eclipse does point to the previously browsed location after I click the browse button** but I need to know the previously browsed location even before I click browse button so that it can be displayed in the `Text` control.

I found some suggestions on this site - https://dzone.com/articles/remember-state but I don't think it would help me in remembering the state of the browse location with respect to `FileDialog`

Please correct me if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `IDialogSettings` mentioned in the link to save and restore information for a wizard. Wizards provide some methods to help.

In the constructor of your main `Wizard` class set the dialog settings the Wizard should use. This might be:

```java
public MyWizard()
{ 
  setDialogSettings(Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings());
}
```

where `Activator` is the activator for your plug-in (this only works if the activator extends `AbstractUIPlugin`).

Once you have done this your `WizardPage` can access the settings:

```java
IDialogSettings settings = getDialogSettings()
```

When the File Dialog returns the location you can save that in the settings:

```java
settings.put("path", path);
```

When you are creating the file path `Text` you can check if you have a saved value:

```java
String savedPath = settings.get("path");
if (savedPath != null) {
  filePathText.setText(savedPath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this approach but can you tell me which package this Activator class belongs to? I found it in three different packages - org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime, org.eclipse.core.internal.content and org.eclispe.core.internal.preferences.

Comment: It is the Activator for your plug-in - you may not have created one.

Comment: Got your point, I will create one and try this approach. Thank you

Comment: This worked, thanks again and just one minor edit, instead of settings.set(key,value) it should be settings.put(key,value).